# Zend_pdf: How to create repeated pdf footer with Zend_Pdf_Table Component

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have created a pdf file containing a table in many pages and I'm trying to add a repeated footer (in each page) to my document.

How can I do that with Zend_Pdf_Table Component ?

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I hope this will help you 

/*** TABLE_HEADER **/
            $page_header = new My_Pdf_Table(0);
            //header row
            $row_h = new My_Pdf_Table_Row();    
            //header left column
            $head_left = new My_Pdf_Table_Column();             
            $head_left->setText("Students Header");                      
            $cols_header[] = $head_left;    
            //header right column
            $head_right = new My_Pdf_Table_Column();
            $head_right->setText("");                   
            $cols_header[] = $head_right;

            $row_h->setColumns($cols_header);
            $page_header->addRow($row_h);               

            /*** TABLE_HEADER ends **/

            /*** TABLE FOOTER ***/
            $page_footer = new My_Pdf_Table(0);
            //footer row
            $row_f = new My_Pdf_Table_Row();    

            //footer left column
            $col_left = new My_Pdf_Table_Column();
            $col_left->setText("Students footer");   
            $cols_footer[] = $col_left; 

            //footer right column
            $col_right = new My_Pdf_Table_Column();
            $col_right->setText("@@CURRENT_PAGE");   
            $cols_footer[] = $col_right;

            $row_f->setColumns($cols_footer);
            $page_footer->addRow($row_f);   
            /*** TABLE FOOTER ends***/
```

after your logic add following lines

```
                  // in code after ur logic             

            $pdf->setHeader($page_header);
            $pdf->setFooter($page_footer);

            // add table to page                 
            $page->addTable($table, 10, 10);
```

and you will get your header and footer.